# Is there a clean way to export a single variable for one line?

Tags: bash

Suppose I have

```
SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME="Some even longer value"
ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME="Another long value"
```

in my bash script.

I need to pass those to some commands (e.g. `SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME=$SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME=$ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME someCommand`)

Short of exporting said variable, is there a way to inform bash to pass the value of SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME to only that one command without also explicitly expanding the value?

E.g. something like `pass SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME,ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME someCommand` would be equivalent to `SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME=$SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME=$ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME someCommand`

The best I've come up with is this:

```bash
function passValues() {
    varArray=($(echo $1 | tr ',' '\n'))
    expandedVars=($(for v in "${varArray[@]}"; do echo "$v=${!v}"; done))
    env "${expandedVars[@]}" "${@:2}"
}

SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME="Some even longer value"
ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME="Another long value"

# obviously not what my real someCommand is, but this demonstrates this seems to work
pass SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME,ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME sh -c 'echo A=$SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME B=$ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME'
```

This seems to work, but I'm not sure how I feel about it, since it's sorta nonstandard.

```
passValues SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME,ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME \
    sh -c 'echo A=$SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME B=$ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME'
```

may be shorter than

```
SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME=$SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME \ 
    ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME=$ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME \
    sh -c 'echo A=$SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME B=$ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME'
```

but I'm not sure it's *better*.

Is there any sort of built-in or common shell program that will do this? If not, do people feel this function is more likely to cause confusion than improve readability?

Comment: I would absolutely just use your last version, with the explicit line continuations.

Comment: Try: `echo ${SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME@A} ${ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME@A} `

Comment: Or even `for v in SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME;do declare -n refvar=$v;echo ${refvar@A};done`

Comment: Maybe you need to use `export SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME` before running `sh -c '...` Then you could `unset` your variables if you won't them to exist further...

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub `x=10; echo "($x)"; env ${x@A} bash -c 'echo "($x)"'` seems odd (extra quotes). did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap inside parentheses, you get a concise syntax which does not require explicitly expanding the variable values:

```
(
  export SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME
  exec someCommand
)
```

This does use `export` but the commands execute in a subshell environment and so the changes to the environment do not persist.

You can still perform input and output redirections; and the exit status will be that of `someCommand`.

---

If you really wanted, you could define your `pass` as:

```
pass()( export ${1//,/ }; exec "${@:2}" )
```

Comment: Make it `exec someCommand` and this runs with no performance penalty (since the subshell gets consumed).

Answer (score 0):

With the `-k` option, you can write

```
set -k

sh -c 'echo A=$SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME B=$ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME' \
    SOME_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME="Some even longer value" \
    ANOTHER_LONG_VARIABLE_NAME="Another long value"

set +k  # Turn it off again
```

The `-k` option makes *all* assignment arguments act like environment modifiers, not just the ones that precede the command.

I don't see anything wrong with how you similarly used line continuations with pre-command modifiers, though.